# Url compartida en RRSS con imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css, prestashop

He estado buscando por internet como hacer que por ejemplo cuando envío una dirección de una web vía WhatsApp aparezca una foto junto con este enlace y no solo el enlace, pero no me aparece la información que necesito.

Alguien sabe como se podría hacer esto?

Cuando comparto la web no aparece ninguna imagen, pero al compartir un producto si aparece la imagen de este producto.

he probado

`<meta property="og:image" content=" http://example.com/image.jpg" />`

Tambien he probado:

`<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image"  content=" http://example.com/image.jpg" />`

Pero no funciona correctamente.

Edit: Mandando el enlace a través del movil si aparece la foto, pero si lo envío vía whatsapp Web no funciona.

Comment: En Whatsapp Web a veces debes esperar unos segundos para que se consulte el enlace y se agregue la foto, otras veces, debes teclear algo más y, otras, nunca se agrega. En mi caso, estoy seguro que cuando falla es porque la conexión a Internet está muy lenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ciertamente al cabo de un rato apareció la imagen, pude imaginar que era algún tipo de tiempo que necesitaba el servidor para procesar el nuevo dato.